# Target group 443 gives Health checks failed with these codes: [502]

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

I wanted to deploy a Laravel website to amazon, so I did the following steps:

- Deployed the Laravel App using Elastic Beanstalk
- Configured Route:53 A instance to point to the Ip of Ec2
- Created Application Load Balancer with two listeners one at 80 and one at 443
- Created 2 target groups Tg80 and Tg443 and designate the listener respectively
- Note that Tg443 has a valid SSL certificate
- Changed the security group of the Ec2 to be the Load balancer's one
- Changed the A instance in Route:53 to be the load balancer's

**Results: **

- The site works perfectly on port 80 with http, same for health check,  and I can acces the site normally from any browser
- The site returns [502 Bad Gateway] on https:443
- In (After ssh to instance) /var/log/httpd/error_log I have the following error `/var/www/html/.htaccess: RewriteCond: bad flag delimiters`

**So, I tried**, According to the link [enforce-https-laravel](https://therightsw.com/enforce-https-laravel/):

- To configure `.htaccess` in the laravel app as said in the link, refreshed everything `php artisan config:cache, retried health check but **Same Results**
- The I deleted `.htaccess` and configured `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`:

```
    use Illuminate\Contracts\Routing\UrlGenerator; 

    public function boot(UrlGenerator $url)
    {
       if(env('ENFORCE_SSL', false)) {
         $url->forceScheme('https');
       }
    }
```

- And added `ENFORCE_SSL=true` in `.env` and then `php artisan config:cache` as said in the same *link* it is a newer way than `.htaccess`.

**But Same Results**

**I don't know what to do net or how to fix this.** **I want to be able to access the site with ssl. Please Help. Thank you.**

[image]

Comment: Do you install SSL certificate on your server?

Comment: No I installed Load balancer 443

Comment: Check the image @JesusErwinSuarez

Comment: I just added it

Comment: I installed the SSL certificate on listener:443 on the load balancer

Comment: Side note. If you use R53 and EBstalk, it would be better to point R53 to EBstalk env, not its load balancer. Also better to use Alias record (which is free), rather than A record (which is not free)

Comment: And to clarify which HChecks fail? R53 Health CHecks, or your for ELB? Also you use SSL between ELB and your EC2?

Comment: The target group 443 HCheck failed with error 502 bad gateway @Marcin

Comment: And the SSL is on the Application load balancer HTTPS:443 listener

Comment: And R53 of A type has Alias target of SiteLoadBalancer

Comment: Yes, but then why you have any enformcemnt of ssl on the EC2? And what .htaccess has to do with it if the ssl is on the ELB? Your healthcheck between ELB and EC2 should be in HTTP, not HTTPS, unless you have some special requirements. And if you do, then you have to provide self-signed certificates for the EC2.

Comment: Ok so the problem is on the level between EC2 and ELB

Comment: So I should remove the SSL enforcement on EC2

Comment: So how to fix it once I remove the SSL enforcement on EC2

Comment: If R53 points to elastic beanstalk,  then where should I put the SSL certifcate

Comment: Forgive me this my first deployment ever

Comment: I think so. For the `tg433` use HTTP for health check, just like for the `tg80`.  ALB terminates your SSL connection, so all trafic between ELB and EC2 is in HTTP. And this is sufficient for majority of cases. Thus health checks should also be HTTP.

Comment: OK I'll try that and see hope it is fixed

Comment: @Marcin I removed the ssl enforcement on ec2 and the tg443 now uses https and it worked now I have SSL installed... But that messed up the css in the site, any idea how to fix that

Comment: Good to hear that health checks work, but don't know much how larver works. I will make anwser that the issue was with https between elb and ec2. There is so many comments here, that people may find it difficult to see what has been discussed.

Comment: No problem. Hope that CSS will also get solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based the comments, the issue was that the health checks were set to use HTTPS between ALB and EC2. However, since ALB terminates the SSL connections, all traffic between ALB and EC2 is in HTTP, not HTTPS.

Therefore, the solution to not working health checks was to use HTTP for them, rather then HTTPS.